# Find all numbers which are equal to the sum of the factorial of their digits

Tags: matlab

How can Find all numbers (e.g. 145= 1! + 4! + 5! = 1 + 24 + 120 = 145.)
 which are equal to the sum of the factorial of their digits, by MATLAB?

I want to chop off digits, add the factorial of the digits together and compare it with the original number. If factorial summation be equal to original number, this numbers is on of the solution and must be keep. I can't code my idea, How can I code it? Is this true?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by you cannot code? Is this true? No it is false. You can code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snippet finds the numbers up to 1000 satisfying this condition.

```
numbers = [];
for i=1:1000
  number_char = int2str(i);
  sum = 0;
  for j=1:length(number_char)
   sum = sum+ factorial(eval(number_char(j)));
  end
  if (sum == i)
     numbers(end+1) = i;
  end
end
disp(numbers)
```

This should yield:

```
1  2  145
```

Note that if (log10(n)+1)*9! is less than n, then there is no number satisfying the condition larger than n.

Comment: [No need to use `eval` here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54136613/2627163)

Comment: To explain for the less versed reader: The eval function indeed cannot always be pre-compiled, and hence is slow and generally not recommended. The char difference trick is neat and efficient. I wrote this piece of code to be simple, avoiding for instance the function handle(@). Yet again, if efficiency is your concern, the [numbers,i] should also be avoided, although in this case the operation is very rarely performed. However, note that allocating a vector for booleans as in the other answer is not optimal, since for all numbers one should pre-allocate a vector with length around 10000000.

Comment: My main concern with `eval` was not its performance, but that it's a [very bad habit to use this function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html). I agree that preallocating here is not really necessary, though knowing that requires some heuristics about the code, which I prefer to avoid in simple usage examples.

Answer (score 4):

*The main reason that I post this answer is that I can't leave the use of `eval` in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54134329/2627163) without a decent alternative*

Here is a small function to check this for any given (integer) `n`:

```
isFact = @(n) n==sum(factorial(int2str(n)-'0'));
```

Explanation:

1. `int2str(n)-'0'`: "chop off digits"
2. `sum(factorial(...))`: "add the factorial of the digits together"
3. `n==...`: "compare it with the original number"

You can now plug it in a loop to find all the numbers between 1 to `maxInt`:

```
maxInt = 100000; % just for the example
solution = false(1,maxInt); % preallocating memory
for k = 1:maxInt
    solution(k) = isFact(k);
end
find(solution) % find all the TRUE indices
```

The result:

```
ans =
           1           2         145       40585
```

---

The loop above was written to be simple. If you look for further efficiency and flexibility (like not checking all the numbers between 1 to `maxInt` and checking array in any shape), you can change it to:

```
% generating a set of random numbers with no repetitions:
Vec2Check = unique(randi(1000,1,1000)); % you can change that to any array
for k = 1:numel(Vec2Check)
    if isFact(Vec2Check(k))
        Vec2Check(k) = Vec2Check(k)+0.1;
    end
end
solution = Vec2Check(Vec2Check>round(Vec2Check))-0.1
```

The addition of 0.1 serves as a 'flag' that marks the numbers that `isFact` returns `true` for them. We then extract them by comparing the vector to it's rounded vertsion.

---

You can even go with a one-line solution:

```
solution = nonzeros(arrayfun(@(n) n.*(n==sum(factorial(int2str(n)-'0'))),Vec2Check))
```